# how do I filter an array of objects using multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to be able to filter an array of data by multiple parameters:

```
const data = [{
    userId: '7',
    id: '1',
    title: 'quo provident culpa',
    body: "a",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    userId: '7',
    id: '2',
    title: 'natus commodi et',
        body: "a",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    userId: '1',
    id: '3',
    title: 'voluptatem et reprehenderit',
    body: "c",
    completed: false
  }
];

const query = {
  title: 'l',
  body: 'a'
}
```

I've tried this:

```
const filterData = (data, query) => {
  return data.filter(rec => {
    return Object.keys(query)
      .find(key => rec[key] === query[key])
  })
}

console.log(filterData(data, query))
```

My solution is not quite working since it returns any objects that satisfy at least one parameter. In the case above I get this returned:

```
[{
  body: "a",
  completed: true,
  id: "1",
  title: "quo provident culpa",
  userId: "7"
}, {
  body: "a",
  completed: true,
  id: "2",
  title: "natus commodi et",
  userId: "7"
}]
```

but what I really wanted was to get returned only what satisfies both conditions (`title` and `body`) by partially match the string. like so:

```
{
  userId: '7',
  id: '1',
  title: 'quo provident culpa',
  completed: true
}
```

I understand that the find() method returns the first element that satisfies a condition, but this was the closest I could get since I want it to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could filter with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for the wanted parameters and check only with [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```js
const
    data = [{ userId: '7', id: '1', title: 'quo provident culpa', body: "a", completed: true }, { userId: '7', id: '2', title: 'natus commodi et',  body: "a", completed: true }, { userId: '1', id: '3', title: 'voluptatem et reprehenderit', body: "c", completed: false }],
    query = { title: 'l', body: 'a' },
    filterData = (data, query) => data.filter(rec => Object
        .entries(query)
        .every(([k, v]) => rec[k].toString().includes(v))
    );

console.log(filterData(data, query));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the first occurrence just replace `filter` with `find`.

```js
const filterData = (data, query) => {
  return data.find(rec => {
    return Object.keys(query)
      .find(key => rec[key] === query[key])
  })
}
```

Edit: You could combine `filter` with `every` like this:

```js
const filterData = (data, query) => {
  return data.filter((item) => {
    return Object.keys(query).every((key) => {
      return (item[key] + '').includes(query[key] + '');
    }, true);
  });
}
```

Comment: There is no objects with `title: 'l'`. You need to check if the string is included, not `===`

Comment: what happens when he got two entries satisfying the query ?

Comment: I've updated my answer but the implementation was already answered.

Comment: There are still some caveats with number or boolean values in my answer `toString()` ensures that won't fail.